# Does not contain a definition for "foo"

Tags: c#

I am new to Visual Studio C#. I receive the following error constantly when I'm using some of the methods in System.Windows.Forms

> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView does not contain a definition for 'foo' 
>   and no extension method 'foo' accepting a first argument of type System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView could be found

My code follows:

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            int i;
            i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
    }
```

As I said, I've seen this kind of error more than once, but what's the reason it's ocurring here?
Thanks

/EDIT:
As per request I'm adding the whole project:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //.Designer
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.None;

        PopulateDataGridView();
        }
        public void PopulateDataGridView()
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Nombre";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Valor";
            dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].HeaderText = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Nombre"].HeaderText = "Nombre";
            dataGridView1.Columns["Valor"].HeaderText = "Valor";

            //DataGridView.
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "1", "Nachos", "3.00" });
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "2", "Pelukas", "5.70" });
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "3", "Fresas", "3.50" });
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "4", "Mineral", "5.50" });
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "5", "Mirinda", "7.80" });
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "6", "Jamaica", "2.70" });

            // Autosize.
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = button7;
            textBox1.Focus();
        }


        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public DataGridViewRowCollection Rows { get; }

       private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
                int i;
                i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
                textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
        }
```

Comment: You should post the *actual* text of the error message, not modified, and not just part of it. There's no "foo" in your source code, so there can't be a "foo" in the error message.

Comment: ok, the actual text contains Item instead of foo but as I said, it happens everytime. I figured a simple foo would do to exemplify. I'll proceed to complete the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
textBox2.Text = dataGridView1[2, i].Value;
```

Comment: I'm testing this version as I write these words
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString();

Comment: It worked better thatn my previous version `            textBox2.Text = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString();`

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect it is this line:

`textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value`

I can see that Item is a *property* of DataGridView from the Visual Studio help. Furthermore, it is an indexer, so I would expect you need:

`textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Item[2, i].Value`

i.e. parenthesis converted to brackets

With the parenthesis, it thinks it must be a function you are referring to, but it is not built-in to the type, so it starts looking for extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

The exception states you are using a method (`foo`) on a control that does not support it. Can you post the code where this happens?

You have not placed semicolons at the end of your lines. Its not the problem, but it's one of them.

Should look as follows:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value;
}
```

---

There's code somewhere that is executing what I mentioned first. The code posted above cannot generate that exception message.

Comment: I just did. It's appended to the question.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. I'll check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this. You have a class, say, "Car" that emulates all of the functionality of a Car.  What this error is telling you is that your "Car" can not perform the action you are asking it to perform.  For example, Car.Fly(  ); Now, as we know, a Car cannot (currently) fly. So the compiler is telling you that asking your Car to Fly is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered but for some others coming with this error but not this specific class the OP used...

I fixed the error simply by cleaning the solution and rebuilding.